# How to deal with namespace dependencies from other packages when creating a package in R?

Tags: r, cran, ggally

I am creating my own package in R. Within my package I am using the `ggnet2` function from `GGally` package. I am trying to get my package CRAN ready and Im using a bunch of tests from the `devtools` package.

My issue is, I get an error when I run the following `devtools` tests:

```
library(devtools)

check_win_release()
check_win_devel()
```

The error that is being thrown back is:

```
Error: please install the package 'network'.  install.packages('network') 
  Backtrace:
      x
   1. \-myPackage::plotNetwork(vi) test_plots.R:34:2
   2.   +-base::suppressMessages(...)
   3.   | \-base::withCallingHandlers(...)
   4.   \-GGally::ggnet2(...)
   5.     \-GGally:::require_namespaces(c("network", "sna", "scales"))
```

Now, when I look up the source code for `ggnet2`, the very 1st line of code is:

```
 require_namespaces(c("network", "sna", "scales"))
```

In my `NAMESPACE` file I have the `ggnet2` function imported, along with `ggplot2`, like so:

```
import(ggplot2)
importFrom(GGally,ggnet2)
```

And I also have `GGally` and `ggplot2` under the Imports field in my `DESCRIPTION` file within my package.

I have tried adding `network` and `sna` to the `suggests` field in my `DESCRIPTION` file, but the error still remains (I am using the `scales` package elsewhere within my package, so Im importing it separately).

This error is from a test file that I'm using with `devtools::test()` but (on my machine I have these packages installed) I'm guessing that when I run `check_win_release()` the machine that the tests are being preformed on don't have the required packages!?

I was wondering how do I solve this error? Or what are the best practices when importing a function that requires the namespace from other functions from other packages?

Comment: I think `network` is a package installed with the base version of R. So you probably don't need to add it to the list. But that is just a guess.

Comment: I don't believe `network` is installed with base R. IT has it's own CRAN release and I had to install the `network` package when I wanted to use it on my machine

Comment: You can probably recreate the problem using the package `renv`. See https://rstudio.github.io/renv/articles/renv.html . It can create an empty environment for development and then you can test the build, tests and installation.

Comment: Have you tried putting `network`, `GGally` and `sna` in the Imports field on your `DESCRIPTION` file? I suggest you use `usethis::use_package` to add them manual to your `DESCRIPTION` file, in that way there is no need for them to be included in your roxygen2 documentations.

Comment: I was trying to avoid adding `network` and `sna` them to the imports field. I was trying to keep the number of imported packages to a minimum.